# Windows 10 Installation from USB

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install windows 10 through bootable USB. In the installation window, It keep on installing and when it goes to finishing up section. It automatically reboots and after rebooting I am getting an error 'Operating System' not found.

Is there any problem with the windows 10 ISO? Anybody please.

Thanks, 
Awais

Comment: You should ask at [su].

Answer (score 1):

Look into bios and see from which device you are booting from. That might be the cause.

Comment: I am booting from USB, Installation works well until it goes to reboot. And After reboot, it is giving 'Operating System Not Found' error.

Comment: @AwaisLatif you should boot into the storage device that you have installed w10. If this device is not in your bootable devices list in bios, you will get that error.

Comment: I did, it is again taking me to the windows 10 installation wizard.

Answer (score -1):

1.I would suggest to reset your bios

2.set bios to Legacy or UEFI whatever partition system you used while installing window

3.set the boot priority to the Hard-disk

4.Save & exit, Now try booting...